# Not able to view the case attachment(PDF) from Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, attachment, salesforce-id

I am facing one issue related Case attachments(PDF).Actually not able to find what is the problem.

Description:-
We have one standalone application, one custom object(like Case) where we are saving the cases.and one lightning application.

when ever we create a record with attachment, record is going to be saved in Custom object and attachments are going to saved in ContentVersion, ContentDocumentLink. after that we are fetching the same to rendering on the lightning application.

Working Scenario:- When i create a record from custom lightning application with attachment, record is saved and we can able to view the attachment(PDF).

Not Working Scenario:- When i create a record from standard lightning object page with attachment, record is saved and we are not able to view the attachment(PDF).

Workaroud :- The same attachments are having the below same permission 
1)content library permission
2)ContentDocumentLink visibility is "InternalUser"
3)same profile, same user and same owner for the case record.

Thanks,
Ragavendra

Comment: How you are creating the record with Attachment from Standard Page?

Comment: 1) first of all i will go to object from the setup on lightning. Then will provide the required fields then record will create                                                                      
2)Next on the record detail page -> Related list -> Notes and Attachment-> we are selecting one PDF after that attachment will created  and it is linked with original record that was created in setp 1)